# Hide Form when clicked outside of DataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, events, visibility

I have a Form which holds a DataGridView, this Form also loads with an invisible Form which only holds another DataGridView. The second DGV is used to display more information on the items in the first DGV.

The second DGV should only be shown when the user clicks inside the 7th Cell of any row in the first DGV. I have already managed to get it to hide when I click other cells, but I can't seem to get it to hide when I click outside the DataGridView. I have already tried the Leave, RowLeave and LostFocus events without success. I think it is because as soon as the second DataGridView is displayed, it gets the focus and this somehow messes with the event.

Here is my code:

```
public class Form1
{
     Form schedules = new Form();
     DataGridView backups = new DataGridView();

     public Form1()
     {
          this.schedules.Visible = false;
          backups.DataBind();
     }

     private void backups_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex == 7)
         {

             if (this.schedules.getData(Convert.ToInt32(backups.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value)))
             {
                 this.schedules.Owner = this;
                 this.schedules.Visible = true;
                 this.schedules.changePosition(Cursor.Position);
             }
             else 
             {
                 this.schedules.Visible = false;
             }
         }
         else
         {
             this.schedules.Visible = false;
         }
     }
}

public class Schedules : Form
{
    DataGridView grdSchedules = new DataGridView();

    public Schedules()
    {
         this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
         this.Visible = false;
         this.AutoSize = true;
         this.grdSchedules.RowHeadersVisible = false;
         this.grdSchedules.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
         this.grdSchedules.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None;
         this.grdSchedules.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
         this.grdSchedules.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
         this.grdSchedules.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
         this.grdSchedules.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.schedules.Visible = false;
}
```

Users tend to click on the biggest window they see to close popups. You can also do the same with the secondary form; or even add a close button to it.

Comment: this would work, but there is only one little problem: let's say that my main grid has a fixed size of 800x600. depending on the number of datarows, there can be an empty space inside the datagridview control. when I click this empty space, the grid does not disappear

Comment: I am not saying that this is an overall-applicable solution. If you want to account for each single pixel in the screen you would have to rely on lots of different events; although the resulting program might become pretty unreliable. With these kind of problems, rather than putting yourself in the worst scenario possible, just put yourself in the most comfortable/user-friendly case: users want to get everything done intuitively, design your interface with this fact in mind.

Comment: thanks your comment brought me to an idea. instead of sizing the whole grid to the formsize, I set it to autosize and put it into a panel which I, in turn, sized to the formsize. with the Panel_Click event, I can now hide the second form.

Comment: Happy thats it served your purpose. But what if after the getting the popup grid, I click on a different control like a textbox? I think this may not make the form invisible then. Am I correct?

Comment: As said: the more overall-accounting you want to make the auto-closing part, the more events you have to take into account. I personally prefer to rely on "active events" (e.g., Click or KeyDown) rather than on events like Leave; but I guess that this is a personal option. I think that the situation you propose does not happen in the LeonidasFett case; anyway, my solution for this problem would be: associate the auto-closing with the Click event of each single object contained in the main form (for example: textboxes); this configuration should be reliable enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to combine Form Click and Grid Leave event to make it work.

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    detailForm.Visible = false;
}

private void dataGridView1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    detailForm.Visible = false;
}
```

Now if a user clicks outside Grid on form or directly into a different control, then your detail form should be hidden.

Hope it helps.